# weird HTML output

Tags: javascript, html

When I open the html file a weird output comes up.

Phrase-o_Matic says:

> What's it all about?
>   Also isn't there an IDE for JS which can tell me the errors there and then?

I am using Atom as my text editor.

The Code -

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana , Helvetica ,sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script>
function makePhrases() {
  var words1 = ["24/7" , "multi_Tier" , "30,000 foot","B-to-B","win-win"];
  var words2 = ["xyz","abcd","batch","retired","morning"];
  var words3 = ["super","shot","shake","Sunny"];

  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(math.random() * words2.length);
  var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);

  var phrase = words1[rand1] + " " + words2[rand2] + " " +words3[rand3];
  var phraseElement = document.getElementById("phrase");
  phraseElement.innerHTML = phrase;
}
window.onload = makePhrases;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Phrase-o_Matic says;</h1>
  <p id="phrase"></p>
</body>
</html>


}
```

Comment: And a bad question body as well

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, please learn how to read the debug console so you can see your own script errors.

Comment: I am not using an IDE. Can I see the debug console using Developer Console of a Web Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1) '}' at the end after closed "html" tag

2) " var rand2 = Math.floor(math.random() * words2.length);", m must be capital like Math.random().

Below code will work.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana , Helvetica ,sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script>
function makePhrases() {
  var words1 = ["24/7" , "multi_Tier" , "30,000 foot","B-to-B","win-win"];
  var words2 = ["xyz","abcd","batch","retired","morning"];
  var words3 = ["super","shot","shake","Sunny"];

  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);
  var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);

  var phrase = words1[rand1] + " " + words2[rand2] + " " +words3[rand3];
  var phraseElement = document.getElementById("phrase");
  phraseElement.innerHTML = phrase;
}
window.onload = makePhrases;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Phrase-o_Matic says;</h1>
  <p id="phrase"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `var rand2 = Math.floor(math.random() * words2.length);` instead of `var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a lowercase 'm' in `Math` for `rand2`. This should be uppercase.